# How to upload data in the FOREIGN KEYS COLUMNS in remote database from android Sqlite database

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have connected my android application to the remote database and uploading data from local to remote database. In my remote database I have a table which includes FKs`(datatype int)` from the other tables in remote database and I need to upload the user input from my local database in those `FK` columns in remote database table. Additionally, I'm storing all data in local database first and then uploading it to the remote database.

What I'm curious about is:

1. Do the `FKs` column datatypes in both (local and remote database) need to be the same ?
   Currently, I am saving `FKs` input as String in my local database however, 
   in the remote database `FKs` column are int
2. Do I need to create the tables whose `FKs` are attached in my local database too ?

My Opinion:

What I have thought so far however, not sure if this is the right approach is to hard-code the foreign key columns save them in variables in my local database and upload them to the remote server as the purpose is JUST to store user input from the android application to the remote server.

Please help... I have never done this before.Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings? Do you want to check the FK consistency in your mobile app when the data is entered or when it is uploaded?

Comment: As I have created and String array to upload the data in local database. I want to check the consistency when the data is entered.